# Remote login on SSRS from application

Tags: reporting-services

I have an application with Report viewer connected to a remote SSRS. This week , there was a change in my company and the SSRS server was migrated to another domain. Since then, I am not able to get the reports on the application, getting the 401 error. I changed the connection to another ssrs server and added a text box with username(which is the application server name), in order to see which username is connected. I tried to add this user to the migrated server and got:

> "The user or group name 'domain\ServerName ' is not recognized.
>   (rsUnknownUserName)".

I want now to change the log in into ssrs using the logged in domain\username on my intranet network for each user, instead of application servername.
My qustion is:Is it a good solution? How can I do that?Thanks